# Determine whether the series is convergent or divergent by expressing $S_n$ as a telescoping sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+3)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, partial-fractions

I have no idea where I'm going wrong or if I'm even doing this problem correctly.  But here are my steps so far:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+3)}=S_n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{6}{i(i+3)}$$

After solving this:

$$\frac{6}{i(i+3)}=\frac{A}{i}+\frac{B}{i+3}$$

I got this to equal:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{2}{i}-\frac{2}{i+3}\right)$$

So I wrote out the first 4 terms of this partial sum like this:

$$\left(\frac{2}{1}-\frac{2}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{2}-\frac{2}{5}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{6}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{4}-\frac{2}{7}\right)+...+\left(\frac{2}{n}-\frac{2}{n+3}\right)$$

But I don't know if I did this right and I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569663/understanding-the-solution-of-a-telescoping-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac3nn

Comment: A duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569663/understanding-the-solution-of-a-telescoping-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac3nn it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The answer is convergent.
Write $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+3)}$ as

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+3)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{(3k-2)(3k+1)}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{(3k-1)(3k+2)}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{(3k)(3k+3)}$$

(WHY?)

Comment: Thank you but I don't know how to express this as a telescoping sum.

Comment: @inquisitor: Sorry, I have edited my hint to fit the requirement of your question.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  I was able to figure it out using the partial sums I have in my example (by just using more partial sums), but I don't understand how you did it in your answer.  Would you mind elaborating how you got $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{(3k-2)(3k+1)}$?

Comment: You want the first sum to be $\frac{6}{1\cdot4}+\frac{6}{4\cdot7}+...$ so one choice is to use $\sum\frac{6}{(3k-2)(3k+1)}$ if $k$ starts from 1. @inquisitor